# past or present perfect

Tags: past-tense

Which sentence is correct: I had some practical experience with cooking **for over a year.**
or
I have had some practical experience with cooking **for over a year.**
**or ..your opinion
Probably the question is regarding cooking: do I continue to cook or not?
Let us say that I continue to cook, in the present.

Comment: Just like Spanish or Portuguese in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Both of

> - I had some practical experience with cooking for over a year.
> - I have had some practical experience with cooking for over a year.

are grammatically correct, and their meaning is not very different. I think the  first form (using the simple past) suggests that the experience was some time past  and has not continued, but this is not clear cut in the absence of additional context. Either **might** be used in the case where the experience is continuing.

The sentence could be rephrased to:

> I have had more than a year of practical experience with cooking.

But that, by omitting "some" is a stronger statement. Another possible version would be:

> - I have had some practical experience with cooking during a period of over a year.

That clarifies that the experience lasted for more than a year, as opposed to being gained more than a year ago.

Comment: many thanks for the details.

Comment: @Costas  You are welcome. If you think the answer is helpful , you can **upvote** iy using the up arrow to the left of the answer. If you think it is **the** correct answer, you cn "accept" it by clicking the c heckmark (aka tic-mark) just below the up arrow to the left of the post. Only the asker may accept, and only one answer may be accepted per question at a given time, but anyone with 15 rep or more my upvote as many answers as s/he thinks useful. Upvoting and accepting are perhaps the most useful possible thanks. Both add rep to the answer-er, and help others find good answers.